# Unable to compile ACE 6.4.0 on RedHat 7.2

Tags: redhat, ace, tao

I am trying to compile ACE+TAO-6.4.0 as per the steps provided in ACE-INSTALL file, but I am getting following error;

```
.shobj/UPIPE_Stream.o .shobj/WFMO_Reactor.o .shobj/WIN32_Asynch_IO.o .shobj/WIN32_Proactor.o .shobj/XTI_ATM_Mcast.o -Wl,-E -L../lib -L.  -L../lib   -ldl -lrt
/usr/bin/ld: .shobj/Local_Name_Space.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against _ZSt7nothrow' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
.shobj/Local_Name_Space.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libACE.so.6.4.0] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ACE_wrappers/ace'
make: *** [ACE] Error 2
```

The log recommends to "recompile with -fPIC", can anyone please help me?

Comment: Try a `make realclean` and then `make`

Comment: I tried the same but now its showing following error                                                               
../../../bin/ace_gperf -a -o corba.gperf > corba.cpp
s".with key set ""string
s".with key set ""switch
c".with key set ""char
3 input keysigs have identical hash values,
try different key positions or use option -D.
make[1]: *** [corba.cpp] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf/tests'
make: *** [tinset] Error 2

Comment: Looks ACE is now build and it fails when executing one of the ace_gperf tests. Could be something left on the system after the initial failure, you now have the ACE library so you could now build your application.

Comment: The output of mwc.pl is as expected, just informational messages.

Comment: Is following output is correct? erl $ACE_ROOT/bin/mwc.pl TAO_ACE.mwc -type gnuace
MPC_ROOT was set to /tmp/ACE_wrappers/MPC.
Using .../tmp/ACE_wrappers/bin/MakeProjectCreator/config/MPC.cfg
CIAO_ROOT was used in the configuration file, but was not defined.
DANCE_ROOT was used in the configuration file, but was not defined.
Generating 'gnuace' output using TAO_ACE.mwc
Skipping ACE_XML_Utils (XML.mpc); it requires xerces.
Skipping ACE_FOR_TAO (ace_for_tao.mpc); it requires ace_for_tao.
Skipping SSL_FOR_TAO (ssl_for_tao.mpc); it requires ace_for_tao.

Comment: continue ... Skipping ace_svcconf_gen (svcconfgen.mpc); it requires ace_svcconf_gen.Skipping QoS (qos.mpc); it requires qos.             Skipping TAO_FoxResource (FoxResource.mpc); it requires fox.          Skipping Bzip2Compressor (Bzip2Compressor.mpc); it requires bzip2.   Skipping LzoCompressor (LzoCompressor.mpc); it requires lzo1.          Skipping ZlibCompressor (ZlibCompressor.mpc); it requires zlib.           Skipping TAO_IDL_GEN (tao_idl_fe.mpc); it requires tao_idl_fe_gen.

Comment: yes, that are all expected messages

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am getting following error while doing make install on ace or tao ... 
Error PART 1 ...
ACE_wrappers/ace>make install
make[1]: Entering directory `ACE_wrappers/ace'
GNUmakefile: ACE_wrappers/ace/GNUmakefile.ACE MAKEFLAGS=w
perl -ne'if (/^#END MPC-Generated Install Info/) {exit 0}' \
  -e'elsif (/^#BEGIN MPC-Generated Install Info/) {$ok=1}' \

Comment: -e'elsif ($ok && s/^#//) {print}' GNUmakefile.ACE | \
ACE_wrappers/MPC/prj_install.pl -i -s lib_output,header_files,template_files,inline_files,installdata_files \
  -b header_files=include/ace -b template_files=include/ace -b inline_files=include/ace -o lib_output=lib -x installdata_files -b installdata_files=share/ace   \
  /ACE_TAO_INSTALL
/bin/sh: /ACE_wrappers/MPC/prj_install.pl: /usr/bin/perl^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [install] Error 126
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ACE_wrappers/ace'
make: *** [install] Error 2

Comment: Not sure about the last one, didn't see those before. We compile ACE/TAO for RHEL daily, works always, not sure what is happening on your system

Comment: Ok, If I got the reason will update here. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: See http://buildlogs.remedy.nl/rhel70_atcd_debug_ndds523rev0/index.html for a build log of our build for RHEL 7.0

Comment: Hi Johnny, I am getting following message while compiling my module which is using newly compiled TAO version (ACE6.4.0 TAO2.4.0).         ->   tao/2.4.0_test/_debug/rhel7/bin/tao_idl_wrapper: No such file or directory                                                                                                  In old TAO version(1.7.0) this file exist but in TAO 2.4.0, this file is missing. Can you pls help me in this ?

Comment: Can't remember that file, check what it did in 1.7.0 and maybe you can just take it from that tree? Maybe replace it with just tao_idl invocations?